# multidimention array with custom key value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, numbers

hi i have a problem i have two arrays 1 created using php explode function, what i want it to display the number for each word in the array. the reason i want it so that i can link a mp3 file to each word in the list. the file link format to the mp3 are link this: 0000001.mp3 , 0000002.mp3 etc

currently the arrays are producing starting key values of zero for every array:

```
$a1 = array(0=>"Cat",1=>"Dog",2=>"Horse",3=>"House");
$a2 = array(0=>"Bird",1=>"Rat",2=>"Fish");
$a3 = array(0=>"Horse",1=>"Dog",2=>"Bird");
```

//////// i want the arrays to have keys that continue so that i can link them to a mp3 file e.g

```
$a1 = array(0=>"Cat",1=>"Dog",2=>"Horse",3=>"House");
$a2 = array(4=>"Bird",5=>"Rat",6=>"Fish");
$a3 = array(7=>"Horse",8=>"Dog",9=>"Bird");
```

p.s i am not a pro at php i defiantly know there are a couple of mistakes in the php code. http://www.deen-ul-islam.org/quran-player/quran.php

```
foreach ($suraText as $aya)
        {
            $trans = $transText[$ayaNum- 1];
            // remove bismillahs, except for suras 1 and 9
            if (!$showBismillah && $ayaNum == 1 && $sura !=1 && $sura !=9)
                $aya = preg_replace('/^(([^ ]+ ){4})/u', '', $aya);
            // display waqf marks in different style
           // $aya = preg_replace('/ ([ۖ-۩])/u', '<span class="sign">&nbsp;$1</span>', $aya);
$surah2 = leading_zeros($sura, 3);
$ayaNum2 = leading_zeros($ayaNum, 3);
            $aya = explode(' ',$aya);
            echo "<div class=aya>";
            echo "<div class=quran><a href='http://www.everyayah.com/data/Ghamadi_40kbps/$surah2$ayaNum2.mp3' class='sm2_link'><span class=ayaNum>$ayaNum. </span></a>";
            foreach($aya as $key => $aya) { 
            $key = $key+1; ?>
            <a href="http://audio.allahsquran.com/wbw/<?php echo $key ?>.mp3" class="sm2_link"><span class="word"><?php echo $aya ?></span></a>
            <?php }

            echo  "</div>";
            //echo "<div class=trans>$trans </div>";
            echo "</div>";
            $ayaNum++;
        }
```

Comment: Spaces increase readability! Why do you have three arrays?

Answer (score 0):

When you create array, set the key manually and increament it each time you add a new item like this:

```
$i = 0;
$a1=array(0=>"Cat",++$i=>"Dog",++$i=>"Horse",++$i=>"House");
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want seems *very hacky* but you might want to take a look at [array_merge()](http://php.net/array_merge) so you can merge your two arrays into one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$array = array_merge($a1, $a2, $a3);

$a1 = array_slice($array, 0, 4, true);
$a2 = array_slice($array, 3, 3, true);
$a3 = array_slice($array, 6, 3, true);
```